# Incorrect Broadcast input array shape error when trying to use Pretraining

Tags: spacy

I am trying to use spacy's 'pre-train' feature for a NER task, so here is what I tried doing(I am still trying to use it),

**Step 1:**  I started by initializing the model with 'en_core_web_lg' next I saved this model to disk and tested its NER capability on few lines to see if it recognizes the tags in those test lines. (Made  a note of ignored tags)

**Step 2:** Next I created a .jsonl file with new data to train on (about 20 new lines, I wanted to see the model's capability given new data around an entity(ignored tags found earlier) will it be able to correctly identify tags after doing transfer learning). So using this .jsonl and the model I saved earlier file I used 'spacy pre-train' command to train, this created a token2vec .bin file for me (model999.bin).

**Step 3:** Next I created a function that takes the location of an earlier saved model(model saved in step 1) and location of token2vec (model999.bin file obtained in step 2). Inside the function it loads the model>creates/gets pipe>disables rest of the files>uses (pipe_name).model.tok2vec.from_bytes(file_.read()) to read from model999.bin and broadcast the learned vectors to base model.

**But when I run this function, I get this error:**
`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (96,3,384) into shape (96,3,480)`
(I have uploaded the entire notebook here: [https://github.com/pratikdk/ner_test/blob/master/base_model_contextual_TF.ipynb ]).

**In order to pre-train I used this function**
`python -m spacy pre-train ub.jsonl model_saves w2s`

**Here are the 20 lines I tried training on top of the base model**
[ https://github.com/pratikdk/ner_test/blob/master/ub.jsonl ]

**What am I doing wrong here exactly? Please can you also point the fix, I am sure many would need insight on this.**

### Environment

- Operating System: CentOS
- Python Version Used: 3.7.3
- spaCy Version Used: 2.1.3
- Environment Information: Anaconda Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this, the developer(on github) answered my question.
Here is the answer:
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3616